# functions.json graphToken binding ignored by Azure function

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions

I have a function in a folder called 'TestMe', like so:

[image]

I can build the project in VSCode and upload it fine however the contents of function.json seems to be ignored.

My function is pretty simple:

```
    [FunctionName("TestMe")]
    public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, string graphToken, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        return name != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }
```

and the function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "token",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "graphToken",
      "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
      "identity": "userFromRequest"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

I was following the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph) where I thought I could get a graphToken but instead all I got was this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Validate(IFunctionDefinition function,
>   object key) in JobHost.cs
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost+d__36.MoveNext() in
>   JobHost.cs
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost+d__86.MoveNext()
>   in ScriptHost.cs
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Middleware.FunctionInvocationMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
>   in FunctionInvocationMiddleware.cs
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Middleware.FunctionInvocationMiddleware+d__3.MoveNext()
>   in FunctionInvocationMiddleware.cs
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext()

So I tried disabling the function and building/uploading the azure functions again from VSCode but I could still access the function making me believe the function.json is being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using precompiled C# Function, which means you have a `csproj` file and your function is compiled to a DLL and then deployed to Azure.

In this case, `function.json` is auto-generated by Functions SDK and you shouldn't be doing any manual changes to that file. The trigger will be placed to `function.json` automatically, and all other bindings are inferred from function signature and attributes.

So, you should place `Token` attribute on `graphToken` parameter, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph#auth-token---attributes):

> In C# class libraries, use the Token attribute, which is defined in NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.AuthTokens.

Comment: I just tried that, looks like it's heading in the right direction but now I'm getting an argument exception "System.ArgumentException: A resource is required to get an auth token on behalf of a user." Function is: "public static IActionResult Run([
            HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, 
            [Token]string graphToken,
            TraceWriter log)"

Comment: You need to specify `resource` and `identity` parameters in `Token` attribute

Comment: Oh I did try that: [Token(Resource="https://graph.microsoft.com", Identity=TokenIdentityMode.UserFromRequest)]string graphToken, but got an exception: ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: clientSecret

Comment: But you did give me the right answer, now I just have to solve this issue :)